# Custom menu Wordpress: add attribute data-letters="link name"

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom menu :

```
function mfn_wp_nav_menu() {
    $args = array( 
        'container'         => 'nav',
        'container_id'      => 'menu', 
        'menu_class'        => 'menu', 
        'fallback_cb'       => 'mfn_wp_page_menu', 
        'depth'             => 5,
        'link_before'       => '<span>',
        'link_after'        => '</span>',
    );
}
```

And the input in HTML is :

```
<li id="id" class="class">
  <a href="#" data-hash="">
     <span>Start</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

But I want to add data-letters="Link name", so for example :

```
<li id="id" class="class">
  <a href="#" data-hash="">
     <span data-letters="Start">Start</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Walker menu class like this:

```
class MyMenu extends Walker {
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $output .= sprintf( "\n<li><a href='%s'%s><span data-letters='%s'>%s</span></a></li>\n",
            $item->url,
            ( $item->object_id === get_the_ID() ) ? ' class="current"' : '',
            $item->title,
            $item->title
        );
    }
}
```

And apply it to your menu:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu'    => 2,  // menu id
    'walker'  => new MyMenu()
    // your other options
));
```

See this example from the reference: [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker#General_Menu_Example)